# Adding a Google maps on my fragment

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I am trying to add a Google Maps in a new fragment. But i get this error :

> 08-16 16:58:37.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-16 16:58:37.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15409):
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class fragment 08-16 16:58:37.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15409):
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
>   08-16 16:58:37.334: E/AndroidRuntime(15409):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)

Here is the code to launch the fragment :

```
    Fragment fragment1 = new MapsFragment();
    //fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And here is the code of my MapsFragment :

```
import com.rss.main.MainActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_view, null);

//      MainActivity.setShareButtonToVisible();
//      MainActivity.setElevatorButtonToInVisible();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        MainActivity.setShareButtonToInVisible();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }


}
```

And here is the code of my maps_view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Where is the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Refer this maybe get some idea  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/

Answer (score 0):

Your Mainactivty should extend FragmentActivity 
check whether google play services are avilable